# Alias scoping in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm having an issue with a complex query on an SQLite3 database that I think has to do with a misunderstanding on my part of how to refer to columns in a results table returned by a select statement, especially when aliases are involved.

Here is an example table - a list of movie IDs with a row for each actor working on the movie:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_actor (imdb_id TEXT, actor TEXT);
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('44r4', 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('44r4', 'Jane Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('44r4', 'Jermaine Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('44r4', 'Jacob Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('55r5', 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('55r5', 'Jane Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('55r5', 'Nathan Deer');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('66r6', 'Bob Duck');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('66r6', 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('66r6', 'Jermaine Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('66r6', 'Jane Doe');
INSERT INTO movie_actor VALUES('77r7', 'John Doe');
```

I am trying to find out the how many times each pair of actors worked with each other across all movies. I decided to go about this with a self-join, but ran into issues where I would get record pairs such as "John Doe, Jane Doe, 3" and "Jane Doe, John Doe, 3" - this is really the same thing, and I wanted to only count the first version. This is the code that resulted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN d.actor_1 > d.actor_2 THEN d.actor_1 ELSE d.actor_2 END d.actor_1, 
    CASE WHEN d.actor_2 > d.actor_1 THEN d.actor_2 ELSE d.actor_1 END d.actor_2, 
    d.v 
FROM ( 
    SELECT c.actor_1 AS actor_1, c.actor_2 AS actor_2, COUNT(*) AS v 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT a.actor AS actor_1, b.actor AS actor_2 
        FROM movie_actor a JOIN movie_actor b ON a.imdb_id=b.imdb_id 
        ) AS c 
    WHERE c.actor_1 <> c.actor_2 
    GROUP BY c.actor_1, c.actor_2 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
    LIMIT 20 
    ) 
    AS d
```

This doesn't run, but I can't figure out why. My assumption is that I am not using aliases properly, but I really don't know. Any ideas?

([SQL Fiddle link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/279ffa/1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get a simpler query, if we add the condition `a.actor < b.actor`. This excludes pairs with equal actors and at the same time it removed the need of swapping actors.

```
SELECT
    a.actor AS actor_1, b.actor AS actor_2, COUNT(*) AS v
FROM
    movie_actor a
    INNER JOIN movie_actor b
        ON a.imdb_id = b.imdb_id
WHERE
    a.actor < b.actor
GROUP BY a.actor, b.actor
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, a.actor, b.actor 
LIMIT 20
```

Note: SQL always creates a cross product when joining, i.e. it creates all possible combinations of records that match the join condition. Therefore for imdb `55r5` (including 3 actors) it will first generate the following 3 x 3 = 9 pairs:

```
John Doe      John Doe
John Doe      Jane Doe
John Doe      Nathan Deer
Jane Doe      John Doe
Jane Doe      Jane Doe
Jane Doe      Nathan Deer
Nathan Deer   John Doe
Nathan Deer   Jane Doe
Nathan Deer   Nathan Deer
```

Then the WHERE-clause excludes all a >= b pairs and we get

```
John Doe      Nathan Deer
Jane Doe      John Doe
Jane Doe      Nathan Deer
```

Comment: Your query doesn't return what you say it does, based on the OP's data. (Returns only one row.)

Comment: The having clause condition should be `>=2`.

Comment: This works! And thank you for the explanation. I am confused as to what is being compared when you use the > operator on two strings -- is that just string length? Or some other value?

Comment: The string comparision works on the lexical order: `'xyz' > 'abc'`.

Comment: Changing the inequality in the HAVING clause still returns no rows for Nathan Deer.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) > 2` is not clear. If you only want those who worked together in more than one movie, the condition should be `COUNT(*) > 1` or  `COUNT(*) >= 2`

Comment: Nathan Deer acted only in one movie. I would simply drop the condition, if you want counts of 1 as well. (Counts of 0 will never appear anyway).

Comment: Sorry all - the HAVING statement is a bit of a red herring. It was left over from when I was debugging something else; it can be safely disregarded. I am curious though - where does the original code go wrong?

Comment: After the `CASE ... END` you have `d.actor_1`. The new alias should be `AS actor_1` instead.

Comment: Your swapping logic was wrong. It should be `CASE WHEN d.actor_1 > d.actor_2 THEN d.actor_1 ELSE d.actor_2 END AS actor_1, 
    CASE WHEN d.actor_1 > d.actor_2 THEN d.actor_2 ELSE d.actor_1 END AS actor_2` I think. You inverted the condition as well as the output fields, therefore the second CASE gives the same result as the first one. Either invert the condition OR the fields, but not both!

Answer (score 1):

Generate the distinct pairs first, then count them.

```
select actor_1, actor_2, count(*)
from (select distinct a.imdb_id, a.actor as actor_1, b.actor as actor_2
      from movie_actor a
      inner join movie_actor b on a.imdb_id = b.imdb_id
      where a.actor < b.actor) x
group by actor_1, actor_2
order by actor_1, actor_2;
```

```
actor_1     actor_2     count(*)  
----------  ----------  ----------
Bob Duck    Jane Doe    1         
Bob Duck    Jermaine D  1         
Bob Duck    John Doe    1         
Jacob Doe   Jane Doe    1         
Jacob Doe   Jermaine D  1         
Jacob Doe   John Doe    1         
Jane Doe    Jermaine D  2         
Jane Doe    John Doe    3         
Jane Doe    Nathan Dee  1         
Jermaine D  John Doe    2         
John Doe    Nathan Dee  1
```